# What's the magnetic field produced by a current carrying circular loop at a point on its plane?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-current

[image]

How do I find the magnetic field in this case? I already know about the magnetic field produced by a current carrying loop at an axial point or center but what about the point on its plane?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the Biot-Savart law to the problem. See [Biot-Savart law (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law)

Essentially, this involves taking the line integral of the current around the loop using

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\oint \frac{I~d\mathbf{l}\times\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}'|^3},
\end{equation}

where $\mu_0$ is the magnetic permeability, $d\mathbf{l}$ is an infinitesimal line segment of the loop and $\mathbf{r}' = \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{l}$.

Comment: Ya... I was try to do the same. But, can't figure it out that way. Could you pls give that solution?